# Difference between two pip3 packages: pytesseract vs tesseract

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

What is the difference between these two packages?

```
pip3 install pytesseract
```

```
pip3 install tesseract
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pip3 install pytesseract` gets me [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract)

> Python-tesseract is a python wrapper for google's Tesseract-OCR

`pip install tesseract` gets me [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesseract)

> Tesselation based Recovery of Amorphous halo Concentrations. The TesseRACt package is designed to compute concentrations of simulated dark matter halos from volume info for particles generated using Voronoi tesselation.

Answer (score -3):

Both are OCR wrappers for Python; however, pytesseract is based on Googles OCR API and tesseract isn't. I would suggest using pytesseract based on the fact that it will be maintained better, but with that being said, try them both out and use whichever works better for you.

Comment: How does your answer correspond to Anomitra's link to the `tesseract` package?